# Creating a iframe search page for my site

Tags: php, html, forms

It is very difficult for me to put in words my query. But I will try.

I have a site xyz.com which has search facility for listed products. The search page url is generated like this :www.wyz.com/search/search_term

I want to create a iframe page in a third party site with a search facility which can directly communicated with my site xyz.com.

I have tried to create a search box with a submit button. I want to append the search query in as a variable to my form action url string. 
So the search string should look like this :www.wyz.com/search/my_string_variable

## The code I have written is:

```
<?php
$url='http://www.xyz.com/search/';
?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$r1=$_POST['num1'];
   }
  ?>
<?php
$result=$url.$r1
?>

<html><body>
<form action="<?php echo $result; ?>" method="post">
Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

==================================================================
But output what I get, is only "http://www.xyz.com/search/". It removes my variable from the url. I am not able to find what is the reason? I have also tried to print result via  to check the actual output and it shows that it has added the value at the end of url. But when I want to achieve the same thing via form action it does not work. please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <?php
    $url='http://www.xyz.com/search/';
    ?>

   <?php

     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
      $r1=$_POST['num1'];
      $result=$url.$r1;
      header("location:$result");
      }
     ?>

     <html><body>
     <form action="" method="post">
     Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
     </body></html>
```

Please try the above code. I have made some modifications. The main reason your code is not working is whenever you press the submit button it is going to the the url "http://www.xyz.com/search/" directly .The if condition is never executed. In the above mentioned code it will work properly

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it is throwing error :  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: hi is there any other redirect in the code? or are you doing any echo before the redirect code? It is working fine in my end :( Are you using this code in the iframe or as individual page?

Comment: if you are using in iframe, in the form action part just mention the page in which the code is present instead of leaving it empty

Comment: I have tried to re run the code I have uploaded this code on my server but the same error is coming: file name try6.php   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at website_folder/try6.php:5) in website_folder/try6.php on line 11

Comment: Hi Navneeth I have removed the blank lines and it worked like a charm. I have tested it in single window environment. Hopefully it works under Iframe as well. Many thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

action="" - you are submitting to the wrong url. Here is alternate version -

```
<?php $url='http://www.xyz.com/search/';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $r1=$_POST['num1']; header("Location: ".$r1); // 302 redirection
} 
?>

<html><body> <form target="_SELF" method="post"> Num1:<input name="num1" type="text" /><br /> <input type="submit" name="submit" /> </form> </body></html>
```

Comment: Hi Akshay,thanks for the quick reply. I have tested your version. But as I have mentioned in my query I am planning to upload this code via iframe to a third party site for example abc.com. Now with this code the search string generated as www.abc.com/search_variable and it is not directing to xyz.com.

Comment: Is your xyz.com google.com? :) Some sites send out a header which prevents those sites to be loaded in an iframe

Comment: Nope, XYZ.com site belongs to me. I want search result from my site. The abc.com is third party site where I will host this code.